# Is there a good, solid reference for proper RDoc syntax?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I'm looking for a good, solid reference for proper RDoc syntax. Recommendations? I can't seem to find anything that clearly shows:

1. How to document class methods and their parameters
2. How to document what a class or class method does.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An official rdoc example can be found [here](https://ruby.github.io/rdoc/ExampleRDoc_rdoc.html), with its [GitHub source](https://github.com/ruby/rdoc/blob/master/ExampleRDoc.rdoc).

The documentation at [rdoc.rubyforge.org](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc.html) seems to be more complete than the version at [rdoc.sourceforge.net](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html) (which incidentally has a 2003 modified date).

Also, there is a great source of examples: the Ruby core and stdlib documentation. For example, take a look at one of the class methods from the [`File` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/File.html):

> **File.atime(file_name) => time**
>
> Returns the last access time for the
>   named file as a Time object).
>
> `File.atime("testfile")   #=> Wed Apr 09 08:51:48 CDT 2003`

You can view the original source code, including the RDoc markup, by clicking on the first line (in the actual RDoc page, not in the quote I included in this answer). In this case, the method was implemented in C, but the RDoc formatting is the same as if it was implemented in Ruby:

```
/*
 *  call-seq:
 *     File.atime(file_name)  =>  time
 *  
 *  Returns the last access time for the named file as a Time object).
 *     
 *     File.atime("testfile")   #=> Wed Apr 09 08:51:48 CDT 2003
 *     
 */
```

From this you can see that `call-seq:` lets you replace the method name and parameters with text of your choosing, which is very useful for class methods. It also shows how you can display example code in a monospaced font by indenting it, similar to Markdown.

Comment: I was just looking for this. Note that http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Markup.html has the (as it seems) official spec. Search for: *RDoc Markup Reference* **Darn! I really should have read the second comment too**

Comment: Not sure if that applies to newer versions as well, but with my 1.9.3 ruby, it doesn't seem to support the `--markup` option (trying to use [`markdown`](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) mentioned at http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Markup.html#label-Supported+Formats - am I missing something?

Comment: rubyforge links dead.

Comment: http://docs.seattlerb.org/rdoc/RDoc/Markup.html is the only working link left on this page. Edit your answer to use that one?

Comment: I wasn't able to find the link to the source code as mentioned in the answer (which says it's accessed by "clicking on the first line (in the actual RDoc page, not in the quote I included in this answer)". Here's the link to the [Ruby File module source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0d3591f250bfe90805cac3c2d5bbfcadb720df37/file.c#L2067-L2077)

Comment: Most of these links are broken or do not contain complete answers. There is only a smidge of markup reference, and nothing about how to document parameters, exceptions, return types, etc.

Answer (score 23):

Since [RubyForge has been retired](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyForge), here is a new link:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/RDoc/Markup.html

Comment: This one also looks pretty current:

http://docs.seattlerb.org/rdoc/RDoc/Markup.html

Comment: old link is dead now with new version.

current:
  http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/r/rdoc-4.1.2/RDoc/Markup.html

Comment: This is absurd.  All the ruby-doc links are dead but this seems to work: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/RDoc/Markup.html  But for how long...?

Comment: This page contains only the most cryptic documentation for handling method parameters, and nothing about return types, exceptions, etc. Very difficult to make any sense of.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best official RDoc markup reference is [MarkupReference](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/RDoc/MarkupReference.html), along with its [Github source](https://github.com/ruby/rdoc/blob/master/doc/rdoc/markup_reference.rb).